# how to solve android studio dependency issue after upgrading android studio by 3.3.1?

Tags: java, android

I installed Android Studio 3.3.1 after that I am struggling with dependency issues someone please give me solution what can i do now?

1) ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:
2) ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:

how to fix this issue???

Comment: share your build.gradle files

Comment: share your gradle file..

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Jitpack repository? You should add following code to your project level gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

If you did, close project and import again. It would work.

Comment: Yeah..I added repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}    but still not working